# how do I use rails helpers in resque jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I'm trying to use some helpers in my resque job and am running into problems. Here's what I've tried:

```
require 'json'

class SoulmateUserFollowing
  tried this -> include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  and this -> include ActionView::Helpers:UrlHelper
  and this -> helper ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  @queue = :soulmate_user

  def self.perform(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    url = url_for(following_user)
  end
end
```

I also need to include the helper with the image_path method and a custom helper of mine located in module ImageHelper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a named route in your config/routes.rb file and then call it from your job class (no need to include anything)

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.following_user_url(following_user)
```

You also have to set in your environment the default host since you are inside 'resque' and there are no http parameters set.

```
routes.default_url_options = {:host => "somehost.com"}
```

Alternatively you can include the url_helpers and do something like this in your class

```
class SoulmateUserFollowing
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  @queue = :soulmate_user

  def initialize(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    url = url_for(following_user)
  end

  def self.perform(user_id)
    new(user_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Great that worked. However I still don't understand why including the url_helpers and then calling user_path(user) or whatever does not work? Also, I need to figure out how to include the rails asset helpers for image_path and my own ImageHelper module that is in the normal rails helpers folder. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: It should work by extending url_helpers or your ImageHelper since you're in a class method not an instance method but then other things may be missing also.